# Organizing SQL data in order of occurence

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to organize my SQL data with respect to the dates from which the items were sent out.

I work in supply chain and want to order my data as 'initial' for the first sku and 'other' for the other sku's based on the PO.

If PO 1111 has sku 123 came in on 1/2/18 and sku 543 came in on 4/2/18 then I want sku 123 to appear first and then say 'initial' beside it. while sku 543 is second and says 'other'.

Also from the above, if PO 12345 having sku 123 on 1/2/18 and sku 543 on 1/4/18 being labeled initial or other.

I also Version 1 and 2 which are duplicates of each other that I need to differentiate from.

For example purposes:

```
SELECT SKU, PO, DATE
FROM TABLE_DATA;
```

If I need to use PL/SQL then I will be glad to take any advice or guidance. I feel as if my request will require an IF statement or CASE statement.

EDIT:

I have multiple PO's tied to one SKU. I need the system to also understand that when it is version 1 or version 2. If it is version 1 and PO 1111 with SKU 123 and SKU 543 I want it to order it by PO and Date.

Comment: You mention "version" twice in your post, but you are not giving any details. Versions of what? How can you tell, from the columns SKU, PO, DATE? Or are you missing a column VERSION in your "example purposes"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `case` and `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by po order by date asc) = 1
             then 'initial'
             else 'other'
        end)
from table_data t;
```

Comment: Consider adding `order by date asc` after the `from` as well.

Comment: I am so close to getting my code to work but it seems to not be corresponding with the date. It seems to only be ordering by PO#. Also could you explain the "=1" ?